# Selecting all users who subscribe to a particular user, but to whom that user does not subscribe

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following table definitions:

```
subscriptions = db.Table("subscriptions",
    db.Column("subscriber_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"),
        primary_key=True),
    db.Column("subscribee_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), 
        primary_key=True),
)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    subscribes = db.relationship('User', secondary=subscriptions,
        backref=db.backref('subscribed'),
        primaryjoin="User.id==subscriptions.c.subscriber_id",
        secondaryjoin="User.id==subscriptions.c.subscribee_id",
    )
```

I need to form a query that selects all the users who subscribe to a particular user, but to whom that user does not subscribe. I can do this already in Python (they probably give a clearer picture of exactly what I want than my description):

```
filter(lambda u: u not in self.subscribes, self.subscribed)
# OR: set(self.subscribed) - set(self.subscribes)
```

But won't it be quicker if done on the SQL side?

Comment: This is more of a SQL question than a Python or SQLAlchemy question. I edited to add the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this were done in SQL, I believe your query would look similar to the following:

```
SELECT
    u.id
FROM
    subscriptions sub  JOIN
    users u ON u.id = sub.subscriber_id LEFT JOIN
    subscriptions unsub
        ON unsub.subscribee_id = sub.subscriber_id
        AND unsub.subscriber_id= sub.subscribee_id 
WHERE
    sub.subscribee_id = :user_id
    AND unsub.subscribee_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I wish I had enough rep to vote you up. Translating this into SQL-Alchemy gives me what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution in SQLALchemy (it's just a translation of the solution by Michael Fredrickson):

```
User1 = aliased(User)
sub = aliased(subscriptions)
unsub = aliased(subscriptions)


qry = db.session.query(User1).select_from(sub).\
    join(User1, User1.id==sub.c.subscriber_id).\
    filter(sub.c.subscribee_id==self.id).\
    outerjoin(unsub,
        and_(unsub.c.subscribee_id==sub.c.subscriber_id,
             unsub.c.subscriber_id==sub.c.subscribee_id)).\
    filter(unsub.c.subscribee_id==None).\
    order_by(User1.name.desc())
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database is Oracle you can use the "MINUS" keyword that will work on sets just like the minus sign in your final comment. The following is a single statement that is structured similarly to a "UNION" query:

```
SELECT subscriber_id FROM subscriptions WHERE subscribee_id = :myuid
MINUS
SELECT subscribee_id FROM subscriptions WHERE subscriber_id = :myuid
```

Alternately, if "MINUS" is not available you can use "NOT IN";

```
SELECT subscriber_id
FROM subscriptions
WHERE subscribee_id = :myuid
  AND subscriber_id NOT IN
        (SELECT subscribee_id FROM subscriptions WHERE subscriber_id = :myuid)
```